# stiffly stable scheme coefficients derivation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

My question is related to derivation of system of equations for following problem:

$\alpha_0 = \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i$,

$\alpha_0 = \sum_{i=1}^k (1-i)^s \alpha_i + s \sum_{i=0}^k (1-i)^{s-1} \beta_i$

for s = 1 to k,
(this is equation 4 from https://archive.org/details/highorderstiffly394jain
 ,page 2).

I would like to obtain expression for values of $c_{ij}$, so that:
$\alpha_i = c_{ij}\beta_j$ 
(example matrix for k=3 can be seen on page 11 (appendix 1) in paper in given link). Can anyone provide me any hint how to rearrange those stuff?
By the way, I understand that here we can assume that $0^0 = 1$ (second term of second equation for s = 1 and i = 1).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply with $\frac{t^s}{s!}$  to get
$$
α_0e^t=∑^k_{i=1}e^{(1−i)t}α_i+t∑^k_{i=0}e^{(1−i)t}β_i+O(t^{k+1})
$$
and with $u=1-e^{-t}$, $t=-\ln(1-u)$,
$$
α_0=∑^k_{i=1}(1-u)^iα_i-\ln(1-u)∑^k_{i=0}(1-u)^iβ_i+O(u^{k+1})
$$
Using the power series $\ln(1-u)=-u-u^2/2-u^3/3-…$ gives you easily the connection between the $α_i$ and $β_j$.

Thus given the coefficients $β_j$ to compute the $α_i$ you form $\sigma(z)=∑^k_{i=0}β_iz^i$, compute and truncate the product $p(u)=truncate(-\ln(1-u)σ(1-u)+O(u^{k+1}))$ and extract the coefficients from 
$$\rho(z)=α_0-∑^k_{i=1}β_iz^i=p(1-z).
$$

With a computer algebra system like [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/) you can do this as

```
A<c>:=RationalFunctionField(Rationals());
PS<u>:=PowerSeriesRing(A);
P<z>:=PolynomialRing(A);

r :=4; k := 8;

sigma := z^(k-r)*(z-c)^r;
uu := u+O(u^(k+1));
p := Truncate( -Log(1-uu)*Evaluate(sigma,1-uu)+O(u^(k+1)) );
rho := Evaluate(p,1-z);
rho;
```

Comment: It works ! Actually in cited paper you have a_i, and I needed b_j, but thanks to your derivation I automated generation of matrix c_ij. Thank you.